# oracle 11g driver to be configured to weblogic9.2

Tags: weblogic

Friends,

I need oracle 11g driver to be configured to weblogic9.2...

Surfing for this found we need to add ojdbc5_g.jar; but no luck.

Can u advise here if u have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you "add" the Oracle Drivers?
JDBC drivers should be installed to `WL_HOME\server\lib`

If there is already an ojdbc*.jar, you should move it to a backup place. You should only have one version of drivers in the lib folder. Otherwise, it will just take the first and ignore all the others of the same vendor driver. Oracle comes shipped with some JDBC drivers pre-installed.

[Read this](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11035_01/wls100/jdbc_admin/third_party_drivers.html#wp1048361)

Comment: Haller,

Thanks for your response. 

We can enable oracle 11g driver in our wls9.2 server through below steps:
 - Add ojdbc6.jar file to lib directory of weblogic like: “$bea\weblogic92\server\lib”.
 - Need to comment out the existing driver specification for Database="Oracle" and Vendor="Oracle".
 - Add new specification for Database="Oracle", Vendor="Oracle" and Type="Thin".